# Selenium XPath: ancestor does not contain

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Find the div with class "bar" whose ancestor does not have class "foo" within the scope of top-level "foo". For example,

```
<div class="foo">
    <div class="foo">
         <div><div>
         <div class="bar"> </div>
         </div></div>
    </div>

    <div class="bar"> </div>
</div>
```

Find the bar not inside the nested "foo".

And the XPath I tried is:

```
WebElement root = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='foo']"));
root.findElements(By.xpath(".//div[not(contains(@class, 'foo'))]//div[contains(@class, 'bar')]"));
```

But the XPath returns two elements. Also tried css selector:

```
root.findElements(By.cssSelector(":not(.foo) .bar"));
```

Not working either.

Answer (score 2):

Try this XPath-1.0 expression:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'bar') and not(ancestor::*[@class='foo'])]
```

It only returns one item: the desired `<div class="bar"> </div>`.

Comment: Sorry. my scenario is to find the element within a scope. Updated question. I tried your xpath, return no results if searching with the scope.Thanks.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. I copied the HTML that OP posted and ran this query with Chrome's `$x` built-in and it returned the single `<div class="bar" />` element that was _not_ encased in `<div class="foo" />`.

Comment: OP, try running this on Chrome console and see if it works:

`$x('//div[contains(@class,"bar") and not(ancestor::div[contains(@class, "foo")])]');`

Comment: My mistake. my actual scenario is to search the bar within a context element. The xpath suggested by this answer works if not in the scope. Question updated.

Answer (score 0):

This one returns only the 2nd bar (at least when I run it...)

```
//*[@class='bar'][(parent::div[@class='foo'])]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to access the direct child div with bar class, then here is the xpath.

```
//div[@class='bar' and parent::div[@class='foo']]
```